# Работа с большими файлами на PHP

Tags: файлы, php

Есть текстовый файл ХХ мегабайт (например 50).

Есть простой шаред-хостинг, т.е. ограничение на память время работы скрипта.

Нужно:

1. Прочитать строки с конца файла, дойти до нужной по заданному условию (регэксп)
2. Удалить все, что находится после найденной строки
3. Записать в конец новые данные

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Копайте в сторону функции [fseek()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fseek.php).

А вообще, если нужно читать файл с конца - значит решение выбрано неверное.

Answer (score 1):

Ограничение по времени исполнения можно обойти, выполняя PHP из командной строки или по расписанию. Останется только блюсти скромность в памяти )

Второй вариант — разбирать длинный файл командами shell'а. Напр. найти номера строк, где встречается паттерн:

```
grep -n profit 50meters.log

5: v etoj stroke est' profit!
```

Дальше — гугл в помощь.

Answer (score 0):

1. Читаем файл, например, 1000 строк
2. Заносим в БД запись о том, что прочитано 1000 строк (как - сами решайте, важно, чтобы было отмечено, на чем вы остановились)
3. перезапускаем скрипт (автообновлением, например)
4. продолжаем с того места, где остановились.